# Guava: How to type a List of powersets of generic Enums

Tags: java, types, guava

I'm writing a function which needs a list of all of the powerSets of three different enums. I'm using Guava's Sets class and I'm having trouble with the typing.

```java
Set<? extends Enum> allSlots = EnumSet.allOf(Slot.class);
Set<Set<? extends Enum>> slotsPS = Sets.powerSet(allSlots);

Set<Set<Day>> daysPS = Sets.powerSet(EnumSet.allOf(Day.class));
Set<Set<Time>> timesPS = Sets.powerSet(EnumSet.allOf(Time.class));
List<Set<Set<? extends Enum>>> allPS = new ArrayList<>();
allPS.add(slotsPS);
```

I've narrowed it down to Guava's powerSet function as the source of my frustration.

`Set<Set<? extends Enum>> slotsPS = Sets.powerSet(allSlots);` gives the error:

```
incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that Set<Set<E>> conforms to Set<Set<? extends Enum>>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>powerSet(Set<E>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sets.powerSet(allSlots)` is a `Set<Set<Slot>>`, so you'd need to use:

```
Set<? extends Set<? extends Enum<?>>>
```

if you want to drop the actual enum type.

Comment: That works, thank you. However, why would the nested set need to be deemed a wildcard? I don't have too much experience with wildcards but wouldn't, for example, both Set<Set<Day>> and Set<Set<Slot>> both be of the form Set<Set<? extends Enum>>. They are both sets and only what they contain differs.

Comment: Wait never-mind, I think I get it. Set<Day> and Set<Slot> are different types. So you need the outer set to be able to refer to multiple types of the same form. Set<Set<? extends Enum>> means you are limited to sets of a single undefined Enum. Is that a valid interpretation?

Comment: The extends on the outer set is needed to stop you adding, say, a `Set<AnyOtherEnum>` to your `Set<Set<Slot>>`, which you would be able to add to a `Set<Set<? extends Enum<?>>`.